# Excel macro input type not returning correct value

Tags: excel, vba, input

I'm trying to delete all cells that have the same interior color in an Excel 2010 worksheet using the following code:

```
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Application.InputBox("Select a cell to remove based on background fill color.", Type:=8)
Range("C3").Interior.Color = Range(myRange).Interior.Color
```

But when I run the code, I get the following error:

```
Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed.
```

I've figured out that even though I'm asking for the cell reference as a range object (`Type:=8`), `myRange` is being set to the value of the cell.  For example, the value in `A2` is "Test." `myRange` should come back as`A2`, but it's coming back as "Test." Any idea why that would be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

`Range("C3").Interior.Color = myRange.Interior.Color`

You have already dimensioned `myRange` as a Range variable, so you don't need to qualify it as `Range(myRange)`.  If you do that, it is trying to evaluate the `myRange.Value`, and that's why you're getting the error.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, David! Worked great!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with Range(myRange).  The Range object can be used in one of two ways; either a string (i.e. Range("A1:B2")) or two other Range objects, representing the top left and bottom right of a rectangle (i.e. Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(2,2))).  You are providing it with a single Range object.

I suspect you meant to do this:

```
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Application.InputBox("Select a cell to remove based on background fill color.", Type:=8)
Range("C3").Interior.Color = myRange.Interior.Color
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Steveo. That makes a lot of sense. I appreciate it.